# change size value dialog in execution time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I´m trying to create property or method that change size of my container dialog builded in vuetify.

default, i need that have it this:

```
<v-flex xs12 md10>
```

i think that if i do a variable property i can change this value in other part of my website. For this, i´m trying thi:

```
<v-flex xs12 v-model="tamanio_dialog">
```

and i added a props in my component:

```
props: {
        formula:            { type: Object, required: true },
        loading:            { type: Boolean, default: false },
        tipoLiquidacion:    { type: Object, required: true },
        tipoLiquidacion_id: { type: Number },
        agrupacion_id:      { type: Number },
        aliasAplicacion:    { type: String, required: false},
        // HEREDA LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO AUTENTICADO
        usuario: {
            type: Object
        },
        tamanio_dialog: ['md10']
    },
```

And when i call my Dialog, i´m sending this property:

```
:tamanio_dialog="md12"
```

and i can show that size of my container dialog have this size, but console log return:

```
Property or method "md12" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

**UPDATE**

in my father component, always set this size to `xs12` when should be `md10` in desktop size but xs12 only in my dialog.

i try with in fill component:

```
tamanio_dialog="md12"
tamanio_dialog="'md12'"
:tamanio_dialog="'md12'"
```

i updated props component:

```
props: {
            formula:            { type: Object, required: true },
            loading:            { type: Boolean, default: false },
            tipoLiquidacion:    { type: Object, required: true },
            tipoLiquidacion_id: { type: Number },
            agrupacion_id:      { type: Number },
            aliasAplicacion:    { type: String, required: false},
            // HEREDA LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO AUTENTICADO
            usuario: {
                type: Object
            },
            tamanio_dialog: {
                type:String, 
                default:'md10'
            }
            
        },
```

**update 2**

i´m try this, in my component that i hope size.

```
<v-flex xs12 :mdProp="mdProp">
```

props in this component:

```
mdProp: {
    type: Number,
    default: 10
 }
```

When i call this component in dialog:

```
:mdProp="12"
```

result, always set size in 12 and mdprop

```
flex xs12 mdProp
```

**update 3**

PaginaFormulasForm.vue (my chill component)

```
mdProp: {
                type: Number,
                default: 10
            }

<v-flex :md="mdProp">
```

PaginaTipo page where i´m building dialog:

```
<v-card-text>
                                <PaginaFormulasForm :formula="formulaNuevoProps.formula"
                                        :loading="formulaNuevoProps.loading"
                                        :tipoLiquidacion="tipoLiquidacionById"
                                        :tipoLiquidacion_id="formulaNuevoProps.tipoLiquidacion_id"
                                        :agrupacion_id="formulaNuevoProps.agrupacion_id"
                                        :aliasAplicacion="'nuevoLinea'"
                                        :usuario="usuario"
                                        :mdProp="12"
                                        @guardar="crearFormulaEnLineaLiquidacion"
                                        @cerrar="cerrarDialogoFormula()"
                                        @toggleNuevoFormula="toggleNuevoFormula"
                                    />
                            </v-card-text>
```

result in webbrowser always in md12, result class in webbrowser console:

```
class="flex md"
```

What i´m doing wrong? thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Vuetify version?

Comment: @NehaSoni thanks for your response vuetify@2.6.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try like `v-model="tamanio_dialog"` and let's `tamanio_dialog` has value `md12` then it always resolves like this, `v-model="md12"` which considers `md12` as a variable that is not available in your data and that's why it throws the error.

So, using these grid classes like `xs="12"`, `md="10"` or `md="12"` could be useful. Try like this-

`child component-`

```
<child-component />
<child-component :md_prop="8" />
<child-component :md_prop="12" />
```

`parent component-`

**Important-** `v-flex` is available only in **Vuetify 1.x** and you are using **Vuetify 2,** so use `v-col` instead.

```
<v-col xs="12" :md="md_prop" />
```

```
props: {
  md_prop: {
    type: Number,
    default: 10
  }
}
```

Here is a demo. You should see that columns are being created according to the passing props.
**(See the result in full_page mode because the `md` class will take effect only on the full page.)**

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `<v-row no-gutters class="mt-2"><v-col :md="md_prop" class="red lighten-4">md size - {{ md_prop }}</v-col><v-col class="amber lighten-4">Hello World</v-col></v-row>`,
  props: {
    md_prop: {
      default: 10,
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</script>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <child-component/>
    </v-card>
    <v-card>
      <child-component :md_prop="12"/>
    </v-card>
    <v-card>
      <child-component :md_prop="8"/>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your time and answer, i updated my question... Not set size

Comment: You are using it in the wrong way. Please read the answer again. `v-flex` is the Vuetify component which has the `md` prop, not `mdProp`, so use its inbuilt props with the passing prop's value like this- `<v-flex :md="mdProp"/>` not like `<v-flex xs12 :mdProp="mdProp">`

Comment: i´m setting <v-flex :md="mdProp"> now in webbroser console i can show in tag this: class="flex md" and when i send data to this component: :md="12" i´m sorry if i don´t understand

Comment: Yes, this is the right way, so what problem are you facing? Or maybe you can provide a code sandbox where we can debug your issue.

Comment: i don´t know create sandbox to this proyect, i have any vue component. My problem it´s that i can´t send data to my other componet always set empty md. Update my question with my actual code

Comment: Why are you sending `mdProp` like this? `:mdProp=[12]`. Please send it like described in the answer, `:mdProp="12"`

Comment: i updated my last update with :mdProps="12" and i have same result. And in my other page not apply md10 that have dafault value

Comment: I updated the answer with a demo. Maybe you can match your code with that. Important thing is, don't use v-flex, I didn't paid attention previously. You should use v-col.